# Htaccess redirect internal error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to create a `.htaccess` redirect that if the user enters the URL `www.olddomain.com/bonus` redirect them to `www.newdomain.com/bonus` and any other pages or root of the old domain to `www.newdomain.com`.

For some time I have been using this code to achieve it

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/bonus/ http://www.newdomain.com/bonus/ [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://www.newdomain.com/ [L]
```

But since last week it just causes an Internal Server Error.

I have figured out that the error is caused by the `[L]` on each line. If I remove it I get no error, but the user is alway redirected to `www.newdomain.com` even if he goes to `www.olddomain.com/bonus`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 ^/bonus/ http://www.newdomain.com/bonus/ [L]
> RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://www.newdomain.com/ [L]
> ```

These directives would never have worked, so it's hard to say why you are suddenly getting the error.

As you suggest the `[L]` flag is what's causing the 500 Internal Server error. This is invalid syntax - but this has *always* been invalid syntax!? `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive. Whereas, trailing *flags* (such as `[L]`), are a mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) feature.

> even if he goes to `www.olddomain.com/bonus`

But neither will those directives redirect the above URL. It will only redirect `www.olddomain.com/bonus/` (*with* a trailing slash). If you need to match the above URL then you need to remove the trailing slash from the directive. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/bonus http://www.newdomain.com/bonus
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://www.newdomain.com/
```